# Magento 2 Images Slider for Custom Theme

Tags: magento2

I have just started playing around with Magento 2 and I've created a new theme based on Blank.

I now need to add an image slider which I want to show in my homepage.

It doesn't seem like maento 2 comes with one?

Is there any recommended images sliders that I can use?

Comment: Here is a good sample with Owl Carousel: http://www.boolfly.com/magento-2-slider-with-owl-carousel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to learn how to create an image slider, you can follow [this guide](http://www.boolfly.com/magento-2-slider-with-owl-carousel/).

Second, try with [a free module](https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2).

Third, go to https://marketplace.magento.com/. ([User Guide](http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/getting-started.html))

Comment: I'd prefer to use an available one but I'm looking for a responsive one, which this free on isn't. As for the Market Place...I just don't understand how you install anything from there...You copy some code and that's the last I know what to do. I'm used to Install buttons and links lol :)

Comment: The Owl Carousel guide can use for a responsive one.

Comment: From the Github: https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2, you can download and install manually on your site.

Comment: The guide for Marketplace: http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get recommended extension from [magento market place](https://marketplace.magento.com/), I personally work with [magestore Banner Slider](https://marketplace.magento.com/magestore-bannerslider-magento2.html) which is free of cost and look nice and have various control from admin.

Comment: I have a bit problem with the market place. I don't understand how you install anything from there into my Magento 2 website. After I copy that code, I just don't know what to do next. Wish they would just have an Install link just like everyone else does :(

Comment: download code and paste into your magento2/app/code/* then run -> bin/magento setup:upgrade thats it. in admin content tab you can see the banner option.

Comment: you mean paste it into a file or into my terminal?